# facebook like photo viewer jQuery FBPhotoBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Creating A Image Viewer with Descriptions Like Facebook - jQuery FBPhotoBox

everything is working good but i could not retrive image name, description and album name

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fbphotobox img").fbPhotoBox({
            rightWidth: 360,
            leftBgColor: "black",
            rightBgColor: "white",
            footerBgColor: "black",
            overlayBgColor: "#1D1D1D",
            onImageShow: function() {

                $('.imgtitle').html($(this).attr("data-title"));
            $('.imgdesc').html($(this).attr("data-desc"));
            }
        });
});
```

---

```
show: function(image) {
        if (image.attr("fbphotobox-src")) this.tempImage.src = image.attr("fbphotobox-src");
        else this.tempImage.src = image.attr("src");

        $(".fbphotobox-tag").remove();
        var index = this.targetObj.index(image);
        this.leftArrow.attr("data-prev-index", index-1);
        this.rightArrow.attr("data-next-index", index+1);
        if (index-1 < 0) this.leftArrow.hide();
        else this.leftArrow.show();
        if (index+1 >= this.targetObj.length) this.rightArrow.hide();
        else this.rightArrow.show();
    },
```

html code

```
<div class="fbphotobox">
        <img src="museumgallery/<?php echo $setdetail['image'] ?>" class="img-polaroid" width="190" id="<?php echo $setdetail['id'] ?>" data-title="<?php echo $setdetail['itemname'] ?>" data-desc="<?php echo $setdetail['description'] ?>"/>

    </div>
```

and the viewer is appended as

```
['<div class="fbphotobox-main-container">',
                    '<div class="fbphotobox-container-left">',
                        '<table class="fbphotobox-main-image-table"><tr><td>',
                            '<div class="tag-container"><img class="fbphotobox-main-image" src=""/></div>',
                        '</td></tr></table>',
                        '<div class="fbphotobox-image-stage-overlay">',
                            '<div class="fbphotobox-container-left-header">',
                                '<a title="Full Screen" class="fbphotobox-fc-btn fbphotobox-a"></a>',
                            '</div>',
                            '<div data-prev-index="" class="left-arrow">',
                                '<table style="height:100%"><tr><td style="vertical-align:middle;">',
                                    '<a class="fbphotobox-a" title="Previous"></a>',
                                '</td></tr></table>',
                            '</div>',
                            '<div data-next-index="" class="right-arrow">',
                                '<table style="height:100%;"><tr><td style="vertical-align:middle;">',
                                    '<a class="fbphotobox-a" title="Next"></a>',
                                '</td></tr></table>',
                            '</div>',

                        '</div>',
                    '</div>',
                    '<div class="fbphotobox-container-right">',
                        '<div class="fbphotobox-close-btn">',
                            '<a title="Close" href="" style="float:right;margin:8px">',
                                '<img src="./assets/images/close.png" style="height:10px;width:10px"/>',
                            '</a>',
                            '<div style="clear:both"></div>',
                        '</div>',
                        '<div class="fbphotobox-image-content">',
                            '<h3 class="imgtitle"></h3>',
                            '<div class="imgdesc"></div>',
                        '</div>',
                    '</div>',
                    '<div style="clear:both"></div>',
                '</div>',
                '<div class="fbphotobox-fc-main-container">',
                    '<div class="fbphotobox-fc-header">',
                        '<div style="float:left"></div>',
                        '<a class="fbphotobox-fc-close-btn" href="">Exit</a>',
                        '<div style="clear:both"></div>',
                    '</div>',
                    '<div style="position:fixed;top:0px;right:0px;left:0px;bottom:0px;margin:auto;">',
                        '<table style="width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;">',
                            '<tr>',
                                '<td class="fc-left-arrow" style="width:50px;text-align:center;">',
                                    '<a class="fbphotobox-a" title="Previous"></a>',
                                '</td>',
                                '<td>',
                                    '<img class="fbphotobox-fc-main-image" src=""/>',
                                '</td>',
                                '<td class="fc-right-arrow" style="width:50px;text-align:center;">',
                                    '<a class="fbphotobox-a" title="Next"></a>',
                                '</td>',
                            '</tr>',
                        '</table>',
                    '</div>',
                    '<div class="fbphotobox-fc-footer"><div style="clear:both"></div></div>',
                '</div>',
                '<div class="fbphotobox-overlay"></div>',
                '<div style="clear:both"></div>'];
```

but it appears to be like in this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wFoS.jpg

http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Creating-A-Image-Viewer-with-Descriptions-Like-Facebook-jQuery-FBPhotoBox.html
this is the link where i got file from

what i am stuck at is i tried

```
$('.imgtitle').html($(this).attr("data-title"));
$('.imgdesc').html($(this).attr("data-desc"));
```

to show in the viewer but it only shows src not data-desc or data-title... and also i want to display the album name too

Comment: so i have no one to answer this quetion????

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by and where you want to "retreive image name, description, album name"? Why do you format your if without proper brackets? Are there errors in your console? Did you do anything besides copying code from a tutorial?

Comment: the thing is i was searching a image viewer showing description. please see the original post i will elaborate

Comment: console has no error, i did... tutorial had no facility on showing title or description. it only shows src link... but i want is title and description to show up in viewer mode

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is bad, but if you examine the code you will see this part:

```
initDOM: function() {
    var html = ['<div class="fbphotobox-main-container">',
            '<div class="fbphotobox-container-left">',
                '<table class="fbphotobox-main-image-table"><tr><td>',
                    '<div class="tag-container"><img class="fbphotobox-main-image" src=""/></div>',
                '</td></tr></table>',
                '<div class="fbphotobox-image-stage-overlay">',
                    '<div class="fbphotobox-container-left-header">',
                        '<a title="Full Screen" class="fbphotobox-fc-btn fbphotobox-a"></a>',
                    '</div>',
                    '<div data-prev-index="" class="left-arrow">',
                        '<table style="height:100%"><tr><td style="vertical-align:middle;">',
                            '<a class="fbphotobox-a" title="Previous"></a>',
                        '</td></tr></table>',
                    '</div>',
                    '<div data-next-index="" class="right-arrow">',
                        '<table style="height:100%;"><tr><td style="vertical-align:middle;">',
                            '<a class="fbphotobox-a" title="Next"></a>',
                        '</td></tr></table>',
                    '</div>',
                    '<div class="fbphotobox-container-left-footer">',
                        '<div style="margin:20px;">',
                            '<span style="font-weight:bold;">Dummy Photo Caption</span>',
                            '<span style="color:#B3B3B3;"> in </span>',
                            '<span style="font-weight:bold;">Dummy Album Name</span>',
                        '</div>',
                    '</div>',
                    '<div class="fbphotobox-container-left-footer-bg"></div>',
                '</div>',
            '</div>',
            '<div class="fbphotobox-container-right">',
                '<div class="fbphotobox-close-btn">',
                    '<a title="Close" href="" style="float:right;margin:8px">',
                        '<img src="./images/close.png" style="height:10px;width:10px"/>',
                    '</a>',
                    '<div style="clear:both"></div>',
                '</div>',
                '<div class="fbphotobox-image-content"></div>',
            '</div>',
            '<div style="clear:both"></div>',
        '</div>',
        '<div class="fbphotobox-fc-main-container">',
            '<div class="fbphotobox-fc-header">',
                '<div style="float:left">Dummy Header</div>',
                '<a class="fbphotobox-fc-close-btn" href="">Exit</a>',
                '<div style="clear:both"></div>',
            '</div>',
            '<div style="position:fixed;top:0px;right:0px;left:0px;bottom:0px;margin:auto;">',
                '<table style="width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;">',
                    '<tr>',
                        '<td class="fc-left-arrow" style="width:50px;text-align:center;">',
                            '<a class="fbphotobox-a" title="Previous"></a>',
                        '</td>',
                        '<td>',
                            '<img class="fbphotobox-fc-main-image" src=""/>',
                        '</td>',
                        '<td class="fc-right-arrow" style="width:50px;text-align:center;">',
                            '<a class="fbphotobox-a" title="Next"></a>',
                        '</td>',
                    '</tr>',
                '</table>',
            '</div>',
            '<div class="fbphotobox-fc-footer">Dummy Footer<div style="clear:both"></div></div>',
        '</div>',
        '<div class="fbphotobox-overlay"></div>',
        '<div style="clear:both"></div>'];
    $("body").append(html.join(""));
    this.settings.afterInitDOM();
},
```

and at far end we can see that you can define in settings `afterIntitDOM()` callback function. There you can change your popup template in general, or the Album name this way:

```
afterIntitDOM: function() {
    $('.fbphotobox-container-left-footer span:last').text('My Album name');
}
```

But since you also want to change the image name and description, than you should use `onImageShow` method/callback in settings, but there is a problem: `this` inside is the image in focus, not the original image in DOM tree. So, I suggest you change core `show` method and add one line at the end of function:

```
show: function(o) {
    /* o is a jQuery object, the original image we need */
    ....
    ....
    if ( typeof this.settings.myShow==='function' ) this.settings.myShow(o);
}
```

Then define your `myShow` callback in settings:

```
$(".fbphotobox img").fbPhotoBox({
    rightWidth: 360,
    leftBgColor: "black",
    rightBgColor: "white",
    footerBgColor: "black",
    overlayBgColor: "#1D1D1D",
    myShow: function(image) {
        var myTitle = image.data('title');
        var myDescription = image.data('description');
        var myAlbum = image.data('album');
        $('.fbphotobox-container-left-footer span:first').html( myTitle );
        $('.fbphotobox-container-left-footer span:last').html( myAlbum );
        $(".fbphotobox-image-content").html( myDescription );
    }
});
```

This assumes you work with this HTML:

```
<div class="fbphotobox">
    <img data-title="Title 1" data-description="Desc 1" data-album="Album 1" fbphotobox-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/fashion/3" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/fashion/3" />
    <img data-title="Title 2" data-description="Desc 2" data-album="Album 2" fbphotobox-src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300/food/2" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300/food/2" />
    <img data-title="Title 3" data-description="Desc 3" data-album="Album 3" fbphotobox-src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/transport/1" src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/transport/1" />
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle/Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jpy5w1aa/2/)**

Comment: everything's good but how can i add effects when i do next or prev??

Comment: I suggest you to create a new question in case you are stuck, but first think if you really need effects.

Comment: can u help me once more... i have images in the page i have integrated this plugin... but when i click other images (other than gallery image) it also opens like gallery viewer ... and i am noob in these jquery thing

Comment: Problem is your CSS selector you use while activating the plugin `$(".fbphotobox img").fbPhotoBox()`. You need a unique class or ID for your gallery container, or you need a specific class to your images. That way you can activate plugin with (for example): `$(".gallery_1 img").fbPhotoBox()` or `$(".img.gallery_1").fbPhotoBox()`. Also, if your group class is `.fbphotobox`, than you can go with `$('.fbphotobox').each(function() { $(this).find('img').fbPhotoBox() })`. If that does not work, please create a Fiddle and new question.